# Why my blade have Undefined Variable - Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-blade

This is on my `routes.php`

```
Route::get('registration/verify/{confirmation}', ['as'=>'verify', 'uses'=>'HomeController@verify']);
Route::get('login',     ['as'=>'login', 'uses'=>'HomeController@getLogin']);
```

and on my blade is this

[image]

then on my `HomeController.php` where the error belong

```
public function verify($confirmation)
{
    $user = User::where('activation_code', '=', $confirmation)->first();

    return Redirect::route('login')
        ->withInput(['email' => $user->email])
        ->with('fuck', 'wtf');
}
```

and I got error like this

`Undefined variable: fuck (View: C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\tridg\local\app\views\auth\login.blade.php)`

I don't know where I been wrong, I'm so confident that this is correct.

**EDIT1:**

I even tried this

```
public function verify($confirmation)
{
    $user = User::where('activation_code', '=', $confirmation)->first();
    // $user->active = 1;
    // $user->save();

    return Redirect::route('login', ['fuck'=>'wtf'])
            ->withInput(['email' => $user->email]);
}
```

Comment: Probably could've chosen a different variable name.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nevermind, The answer is `{{ Session::get('var_name') }}` not `{{ $var_name }}`